# Почему пропадает значение переменной после одного раза использования в PowerShell в командлете Start-ThreadJob?

Tags: windows, powershell

Пишу

```
Start-ThreadJob -ThrottleLimit 500 -InputObject $for_list_pc -ScriptBlock { }
```

Внутри scriptblok, согласно документации, использую $input для доступа к переменной, переданной через -InputObject $for_list_pc. Но при втором вызове $input там ничего нет. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

`$Input` определена как системная переменная. Она будет автоматически очищена после того, как блок отработает.

Вот, что написано в справке:

```
$Input
   Перечислитель, содержащий переданные функции входные данные.
   Переменная $Input обрабатывается с учетом регистра, она
   доступна только в функциях и блоках скрипта. (Блоки скрипта - это
   неименованные функции.) В блоке Process функции в переменной $Input
   содержится объект, который в настоящее время находится в конвейере.
   По завершении обработки блока Process для переменной $Input устанавливается
   значение NULL. Если в функции нет блока Process, значение переменной
   $Input доступно до блока End, при этом в переменной хранятся все
   входные данные, переданные функции.
```

И, в целом, справку по подобным переменным вы всегда можете получить, написав в строке powershell :

```
Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables
```

P.S. Если есть нужда сохранять значения системных переменных снаружи блока, сохраняйте их внутри блока в глобальных переменных, объявленных снаружи.